# Does linearly accelerating a swirling liquid slow down its angular motion?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acceleration, vortex

Say you pour some freshly brewed coffee in your favourite mug and give it a nice stir. As you depart for your desk, does the (approx) linear acceleration you apply to the mug slow the coffee's overall angular speed?

You're welcome to find boundary conditions, but the mundane is what puzzles me most at the moment.

Comment: My first slurp slows it down...

Comment: As does mine! But let's assume we wait until we get to the desk :)
I know (or think I know) that gyroscopes do not sense linear acceleration, but I'm wondering if that changes as we enter the field of fluid dynamics.

Comment: The movement of the mug (and consequently the coffee) due to your walking probably plays a greater role than the (negligible) acceleration.